# How to sent a request by HTTP using relative url?

Tags: http, url, julia, relative-url

There's a HTTP Message like:

```
POST /v1.0/oauth2/accessToken HTTP/1.1
Host:api.dingtalk.com
Content-Type:application/json

{
    ...
}
```

If I want to send it by `HTTP.post` function, I should let `url = "https://api.dingtalk.com/v1.0/oauth2/accessToken"`.
Could I use relative url `url = "/v1.0/oauth2/accessToken"`, and write `"host" => "api.dingtalk.com"` in headers?
I know this is wrong way, I'm wondering how to separate them in two parts while using `HTTP.request()`?

I Tried:

```
url = "/v1.0/oauth2/accessToken"
headers = Dict([(
    "host" => "api.dingtalk.com",
    "Content-Type" => "application/json"
)])
body = Dict([
    ...
])
r = HTTP.post(url, headers, body)
```

get:

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: missing or unsupported scheme in URL (expected http(s) or ws(s)): v1.0/oauth2/accessToken
```

obviously it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With `HTTP.request()`, you can also use a relative URL and a `Dict` object for the headers as you've attempted, but you need to provide the full URL (including the protocol) as the `base_uri` argument, like this:

```
using HTTP
using JSON

base_uri = "https://api.dingtalk.com"
url = "/v1.0/oauth2/accessToken"'
full_url = base_uri * endpoint
headers = Dict([
    "host" => "api.dingtalk.com",
    "Content-Type" => "application/json"
])
body = Dict([
    # your request body here
])
response = HTTP.request("POST", full_url, headers, JSON.json(body))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: url argument in calling `HTTP.request()` is still absolute url, but thx. I thought maybe there's no such a method that can implement it by directly using relative url argument.

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the source for HTTP.jl https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl/blob/master/src/HTTP.jl#L284, you need to pass in a valid URL. The solution I proposed was to separate the two if you wanted to appy separate logic to each part